# How to search through items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**Home.js**

I am using my own search Icon not,from react native elements..I dont know how to do search through items I m getting from the backend...

```
 this.state = {
        data: [],
        isLoading: true
    }

 componentDidMount(){
     API.get_products()
        .then((products) => {
            this.setState({
                data: products.data,
                isLoading: false
            });
        })
         .catch(err => alert(err.message));
     }
```

**Search.js**

```
 render() {
        if (this.state.showSearchBar) {
            return <TextInput
                style={{width: width, backgroundColor: 'white', fontSize: 18, paddingLeft: 10}}
                placeholder={'Search'}
            />
        }
  return(
          <View>
             <TouchableOpacity
                   onPress={() => {
                       this.setState({showSearchBar: true})
                    }}
               >
                  <Image
                       source={require('../images/tabs/search.png')}
                        style={{height: 40, width: 60}}
                        resizeMode={'contain'}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )
```

**App.js**
Here's the home page.which gives the ability to navigate

```
const Inside = TabNavigator(
{
    Home: {
        screen: Home,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerLeft: null,
            headerTitle: "Blue Rocker",
            headerRight: <Search/>,
}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear and it misses informations... If you want to read all your data information, please give us the structure of your data at least.

Since it will certainly be json, you can use the method `filter()` as so:

```
var filteredItems = data.filter(function(yourElement) {
 return yourElement.aCertainValue == yourInputTextString;
})
```

Comment: Where I have to use this?..If in Home.js , but the search icon is in tabnavigator side..see pal I added little info above.. and what are the certainValue and your element

Comment: Ho I see now, never did something like so, usually I place my search bars under my navigation component, since the navigation is for... navigation. BUT the only way I can think of right now is to implement a store with react-redux, may be too much for your app tho... OR you can use the header option in navigation and do as so in your home component : https://snack.expo.io/H16d0uipb

Comment: I have another page for search..All I want is Flatlist, textInput and other things..Ahh but I cant figure out how,,,